# knex can't build a postgresql connection in the right db configuration

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am working on mac and install postgresql database.

```
brew services start postgresql
psql (14.1, server 12.9)
```

I created the role and database.

```
psql postgres
CREATE ROLE helxsz WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER ROLE helxsz CREATEDB;
CREATE DATABASE sales;
```

using pgAdmin4 to connect the database successfully as shown below

[image]

Then I want to use knex and nodejs to connect the database.

```
const config = {
    development: {
      client: 'pg',
      connection: {
        host : '127.0.0.1',//process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
        port :   5432        ,//Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
        user : 'helxsz',//process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
        password : 'password',//process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
        database : 'sales'
      },
      pool: {
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 10000
      },
      acquireConnectionTimeout: 1000
    }
};
  
  // Try to connect to postgres and export it
  const knex = require('knex')(config['development']);
  console.log('[::Stats::] Connected to Postgres via Knex!',config['development']);
  init(); 
  async function init(){
    console.log('[:] init !');
    await createTable() ;
  }
  async function createTable () {
      try {
        if (!await knex.schema.hasTable('stats')) {
          await knex.schema.createTable('stats', (table) => {
            table.increments('id');
            table.string('species').notNullable();
            table.integer('age').notNullable();
          });
        }
        console.log('[::Stats::] Created Postgres table!');
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Unable to create Postgres table. Ensure a valid connection');
      }
    }
```

Running the code gives the error: Error: Unable to create Postgres table. Ensure a valid connection.

I don't see the problem of configuration on the knex, it is the same with the config on connecting to pgAdmin4.

why knex can't build a proper connection.

Comment: In my opinion, it's because your role didn't have permission to create a table. But to make sure this situation happened please add the result of the `error` variable to find why that block has an error.

Answer (score 0):

pg to 8.7.1 , also node to 16.3.1 and knex to 0.95.11, now it worked